# Another way of replacing newlines instead of using tr

Tags: text-processing

I use the command:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

to convert new lines to spaces using `tr` command.

It works fine for single files - but I have multiple files I need to run a single command on... similar to the following command for doing text swapping:

```
find /directory/. -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldtext/newtext/g' {} \;
```

Is there a command I can add to a bash script (like the one above using find) to remove `\n`?

Answer (score 2):

This will work even without any loop for all filenames starting with `file`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ /g' file*
```

For such operations, i prefer perl. Has the same syntax with sed , is portable and don't have all those strange sed parameters.
You can also apply `-i` switch to perl (like sed) to make in-place changes: `perl -i.old -pe ....` (old file will be backed up with extension .old -You can just use `-i` and no backup file will be kept)

If you prefer you can use your `find` command like this:

```
$ find . -type f -name 'file*' -exec bash -c 'tr "\n" " " <$0 >$0.new' {} \;
```

Comment: The `/g` modifier is redundant as there can be only one `newline` in a `line`.

Comment: You need to redirect the output coming from `tr` back into the input filename for as it stands now, it's all flowing to the terminal.

Comment: @speld_rwong Updated

Answer (score 2):

you could simply loop through the files you're looking to run the command on.

```
for file in ~/Desktop/*.txt
do
tr '\n' ' ' < "$file" > "$file"_output.txt
done;
```

Comment: You don't have to put semicolons on every line break. You'll need it only when you want to execute multiple commands in a single line.

Comment: Thanks @annahri

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -lpe '$\=$"' file.data
```

---

- `-i` turns ON in-place editing.
- `-l` sets `ORS = RS = "\n"`
- `-p` sets up an implicit input file read in + automatic print of records.
- `$\` is the `ORS` which is set to `$" = OFS = space by default`.
- Of course you can give multiple filenames to the perl command.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `sed` command you are looking for:

```
find /directory/. -type f -exec sed -i ':begin;$!N;s/\n/ /;tbegin' {} \;
```